# Colors on the x-axis labels in plotly R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I'd like to set different colors for date labels on the x axis so that each month has a different color. 
I'm trying to use the ifelse function and I'm doing something incorrectly.

```
today <- Sys.Date()
tm <- seq(0, 100, by = 1)
x <- today + tm
y <- rnorm(length(x))
TD<-data.frame(date=x, value=y)

a<-ifelse(grepl("2019-12", TD$date), "red", "blue")

ggplot(data = TD, aes(x = date, y = value)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%d-%m-%Y", breaks = date_breaks("2 day")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, colour = a))
```

[image]

Edit date:

```
today <- Sys.Date()
tm <- seq(0, 100, by = 1)
x <- today + tm
y <- rnorm(length(x))
plot_ly(x = ~x, y = ~y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')  %>%
  layout(
      xaxis = list(
      type = 'date',
      tickformat = "%d %b %Y"
      ))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first define breaks for your x-axis, one option is to use the date_break you have called. Once the breaks are defined, convert them into months and assign a colour for every month. Try the below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(RColorBrewer)

today <- Sys.Date()
tm <- seq(0, 100, by = 1)
x <- today + tm
y <- rnorm(length(x))
TD<-data.frame(date=x, value=y)

BR = date_breaks(width="2 day")(range(TD$date))
MTHS = months(BR)
# if you need different years-months
#MTHS = sub("-[0-9]*$","",BR)
COLS = brewer.pal(length(unique(MTHS)),"Set1")
names(COLS) = unique(MTHS)

ggplot(data = TD, aes(x = date, y = value)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%d-%m-%Y", breaks = BR) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, colour = COLS[MTHS]))
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible to use this solution in a `plotly` library?

Comment: Most likely not, it can take in one color, but not multiple colors for the axis tick labels. Another option you have is remove axis tick labels manually add them using add_annotation.. but it's ugly..

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 things happening. Your vector `a` is too long for coloring. You are not showing 101 labels. 2nd, ggplot expands the x-axis a little bit on both sites, adding labels. This makes it a bit difficult to calculate how many december 2019 labels there are. This means that you first have to make the plot, check how many labels are from december 2019 and then you can add the coloring.

```
ggplot(data = TD,
       aes(x = date, 
           y = value)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%d-%m-%Y", 
               breaks = date_breaks("2 day")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, 
                                   hjust = 1, 
                                   colour = c(rep("red", 10), rep("blue", 45))))
```

It is not a beautiful solution, but as far as I know the only one. It you don't want the x-axis scale to expand. Add `expand = c(0, 0)` to the `scale_x_date` function. Keep in mind you need to change to amount of red and blue again.

Comment: is it possible to use this solution in a plotly library?

Comment: You would have to try. There is also a function to convert a ggplot to plotly graph, `ggplotly()`. This maybe makes it a bit easier.

Comment: I add the chart with plotly, can you help me how to add color?

Comment: Sorry, I have almost no experience with plotly. According to @StupidWolf it is not possible with plotly.